# Showing recent post from a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I wanted to show post from just recent post from a specific categories

so far this is what I have but:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $number_recents_post = 5;
      $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($number_recents_post);
      foreach($recent_posts as $post){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.$post["post_title"].'" >' .   $post["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
      } ?>
    </ul>
```

I tried turning it into this but not working

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $number_recents_post = 5;
      $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($number_recents_post . 'cat=3,4,5');
      foreach($recent_posts as $post){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.$post["post_title"].'" >' .   $post["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
      } ?>
    </ul>
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong....

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @pekka i don't get an error message

Comment: Well, what *do* you get?

Comment: @pekka It displays the post from all the category

Comment: Does @codedude's suggestion help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try this (assuming you are using Wordpress)

```
<?php query_posts('post_per_page=5&category_name=yourcategoryname'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>An error Message</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts), you can't use `wp_get_recent_posts()` the way you do:

> **Parameters**
>
> $num
>     (integer) (optional) Number of posts to get.
>
> Default: 10

Maybe codedude's example helps.